# Apache - directory browsing gives 404

Tags: apache, directory-listing

With no .htaccess files and `Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews Indexes` followed by  `AllowOverride None` in the vhost configuration, I'm getting 404 responses from directory listings. Are there some specific modules I need for directory listings?

My active modules are:

- authz_host
- deflate
- dir
- env
- expires
- headers
- mime
- mod-security
- negotiation
- php5
- reqtimeout
- rewrite
- setenvif
- ssl
- unique_id

**VHost Configuration:**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    # SSL
    SSLEngine               On
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /dir/ssl/ssl.key
    SSLCertificateFile      /dir/ssl/ssl.crt
    SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
    ServerAdmin     webmaster@localhost
    ServerAlias     domain.tld *.domain.tld
    ServerName      cl.domain.tld

    # Just a few connection resets so that I don't waste my bandwidth on "hackers"
    SecRuleEngine On
    SecRule &REQUEST_HEADERS:User-Agent     "@eq 0"         drop,phase:1
    SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:User-Agent      "^$"            drop,phase:1

    SecRule REQUEST_LINE                    "://"           drop,phase:1

    SecRule REQUEST_URI                     "^/admin"       drop,phase:1
    SecRule REQUEST_URI                     "^/mail"        drop,phase:1
    SecRule REQUEST_URI                     "^/webmail"     drop,phase:1
    SecRule REQUEST_URI                     \\\\            drop,phase:1

    SecRule REQUEST_METHOD                  !^GET$          chain,drop,phase:1
    SecRule REQUEST_METHOD                  !^HEAD$         chain
    SecRule REQUEST_METHOD                  !^POST$
    <Directory /dir/public_html/>
            Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews Indexes
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    DocumentRoot    /dir/public_html
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: can you paste your vhost configuration here ?

Comment: Added the VHost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this under `<Directory>`

`AllowOverride All`

And make sure there isn't a .htaccess file that disables directory browsing in the directory that you're making the request to (and restart Apache).

**Update:**

Make sure that the `mod_autoindex` module is loaded along with the `mod_dir` module. Without the former, you'll get an error when browsing directories. See this:
[Apache Module mod_autoindex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_autoindex.html)

Comment: That made no difference. I renamed the only .htaccess file  I had to be certain.

Comment: It was just a shot, copied from an Apache vhost with working directory listing. From what I can see, you have the correct options, unless a .htaccess file is overriding it, which you say isn't the case.

Comment: Take a look at the first answer here:
http://serverfault.com/questions/232949/apache-how-to-enable-directory-index-browsing-at-the-doc-root-level

Comment: It was worth a shot. Did you only have the modules I have enabled? I think that might be the issue. I also listed my entire VHost configuration. I even did a grep for "options" and saw no "-Indexes" @dan

Comment: Hmmm...I take it you can serve files from the directory OK, but just not list them? (Checking the modules I have installed)...

Comment: I have this loaded, missing from your list: mod_autoindex. See the docs about it here:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_autoindex.html

Comment: Yes, I confirmed it to on my end too by disabling it. Glad I was able to help. I'll edit my answer now. Thanks for the accept!

Comment: Updated. Good luck!